# VSCode Extension API - Identify file or folder click in explorer context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode 1.3 has added support for adding commands to context menus. Is there a way to identify whether a file or folder is clicked to open the explorer context menu?

```json
"menus": {
    "explorer/context": [
        {
            "when": "????",
            "command": "extension.myCommand",
            "group": "myGroup"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, is there a comprehensive(ish) list of expressions that might be checked in the when clause here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding obtaining a *comprehensive* list of context keys: in recent VSCode versions, there's a **Developer: Inspect Context Keys** command. After executing the command, it lets you pick a UI element:

[image]

After that, the dev console opens, and you can expand the logged object that contains a full list of context keys and their current values in this "scope":

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You can use `"when": "explorerResourceIsFolder"`.

I had to dig through the code to find it (I was actually writing up a response to say it didn't exist and enumerating the possible clause values when I saw it).

As of v1.10.1:

```
config.<any_config_path_here>
editorIsOpen
explorerResourceIsFolder
explorerViewletFocus
explorerViewletVisible
filesExplorerFocus
globalMessageVisible
inDebugMode
inQuickOpen
inZenMode
listFocus
openEditorsFocus
resource (Uri information: path, query, scheme, etc)
resourceFilename
resourceLangId
resourceScheme
scmProvider
textCompareEditorVisible
```

I've submitted [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22482) to improve the documentation for this.

Answer (score 4):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts

is file: `"when": "!explorerResourceIsFolder"`

is dir: `"when": "explorerResourceIsFolder"`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of language ids like this...

```
vscode.languages.getLanguages().then(l => console.log('languages', l));
```

I still haven't figured out how to determine if the item that was right clicked is a directory. If someone figures it out please let me know.

Comment: Lenny, check out my answer. You can use `explorerResourceIsFolder`

Answer (score 0):

A write up about the feature is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8197). But basically:

> - the when is the same as the keybindings-when and can use the same    keys
> - the when can use two new keys resourceScheme and resourceLangId    which are available without an editor - think of the explorer context 
>     menu
> - the when can be a boolean configuration value, e.g    config.editor.lineNumbers

My menu:

```
"menus":{
    "explorer/context": [
        {
            "when": "resourceLangId == sql",
            "command": "extension.myCmd"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I'm still not seeing a comprehensive list. Does keybindings reflect all available options? also can resourceScheme or resourceLangId be used to differentiate between a file and folder?

Comment: @bingles see my answer for the list of language ids. I still haven't figured out how to tell if the item is a folder sadly.

Comment: I don't know if you figured this already,  but there is now an `enablement` available: `explorerResourceIsFolder`