# Explorer/Context Menus. Is it possible to change folder context depending on a file inside the folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I currently have context menus based off the folder in VScode.

I am wondering if I can do context based on whether the file exists inside the folder. An example being if temp.exe doesn't exist in the folder don't show the context?

Can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation.

Thanks,

Trent

This is for a Vscode extension. I've only tried the ability to get context based on filetype.

```
"menus": {
            "explorer/context":[
                {
                    "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder",
                    "command": "extension.runApp",
                    "group": "vm@1"
                },
                {
                    "when":"explorerResourceIsFolder",
                    "command": "extension.provisionApp",
                    "group": "vm@2"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: You can check what context keys are available like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57245061/2631715 - I don't think any of them really fit your case though.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately not. I guess I might have to look a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

This [in operator for when clauses](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_49.md#in-operator-for-when-clauses) looks like it is what you were looking for.  From the v1.49 Release Notes:

> We have added a new `in` operator for `when` clauses. This new
> operator allows for a dynamic lookup of a context key's value within
> another context key's value. For example, if you wanted to add a
> context menu command to folders that contain a certain type of file
> (or something that can't be statically known), you can now use the
> `in` operator to achieve it.

```
vscode.executeCommand('setContext', 'ext:supportedFolders', [ 'test', 'foo', 'bar' ]);

// Note in this case (using an object), the value doesn't matter, it is based on the existence of the key in the object
vscode.executeCommand('setContext', 'ext:supportedFolders', { 'test': true, 'foo': 'anything', 'bar': false });

// Note, this assumes you have already defined a command called ext.doSpecial

"menus": {
  "explorer/context": [
    {
      "command": "ext.doSpecial",
      "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && resourceFilename in ext:supportedFolders"
    }
  ]
}
```

> In that example, we are taking the value of `resourceFilename` (which
> is the name of the folder in this case) and checking for its existence
> in the value of `ext:supportedFolders`. If it exists the menu will be
> shown.

---