# Is there a vscode keybinding 'when' clause to detect focus on an output channel?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a vscode extension which can run a particular subprocess and direct the output to an output channel. I'm adding a keybinding for the command to kill the subprocess if necessary.

I'd *like* to use ctrl+c, as one would do in a terminal, but only when the focus is in the output channel.

I did not see how I could specify this in the 'when' clause for my keybinding. Is it possible?

Comment: Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/57245061/2631715, I can only find a context key for whether the output panel has focus, but not one that would indicate which output channel is currently active.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the `focusedView` is set to the output panel, like so:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "workbench.output.action.clearOutput",
    "when": "focusedView == 'workbench.panel.output'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check which output channel is selected, you can additionally query
*resourceExtname*, e.g.:

```
  {
    "command": "MyApp.RefreshLogChannel",
    "key": "f5",
    "when": "focusedView == 'workbench.panel.output' && resourceExtname == '.myapp-#2-MyApp Log'"
  }
```

To find out what's the *resourceExtname* of your output channel, you can do the following:

- Open the VSCode Developer Tools via Help -> Toggle Developer Tools
- Go back to the VSCode window
- Hit Ctrl+Shift+P and search for "Inspect Context Keys"
- Go to the developer tools window and take a look at the console output