# contributes.menus: what are the possible variables for "when" action

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

At the API documentation of contributes.menus: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#menu-example

There's a field called "when". The example uses:

```
"when": "resourceLangId == markdown",
```

What else variables can I use in this context?

Comment: I've just found the answer on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267360/vscode-extension-api-identify-file-or-folder-click-in-explorer-context-menu